# how to retrieve values of multiple ids stored in a single field in db in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Name : <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
    Activities :
        <?php
            $sql_activities = "select * from tb_activities";
            $query_activities = mysql_query($sql_activities);
            $active = 1;
            while($row_activities = mysql_fetch_array($query_activities)) {
                ?>
                <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$row_activities['activity_id'];?>" name="activities<?=$active;?>"/>
                <?=$row_activities["activity_name"];?>
                <?php    
                    $active++;
            } 
        ?>
   <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" />
</form>
```

Here is my form. Now in this form I am saving two fields name and activities, suppose I entered a name and I choose five activies that are coming from a table, suppose I choose five activities, at the time of insertion I am sending IDs of the activities in the table but not the activity name. My problem is that at the time of editing I want to show the activity names that the user chooses. How to show the names of the activities that the user have chosen? Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you show your output ? i can see you are getting name of checkbox different you can echo them if they set(isset)

Comment: actualy i am very confused how to do that....i asking for a idea that hoe to code for such a thing ?

Comment: check console log or view your webpage source you will know what is your output by all this code ....understandable

Answer (score 0):

you are not clear.i think you are new to php and asking about sql join statement.http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly (and I may not be) if you change your checkbox to:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_id']; ?>"
                   name="activitiesChosen[]" >
```

Then when you submit your form you will pass an array (activitiesChosen) that contains all the visitors choices (as activity IDs).

Then, when you want to display the choices you get the array from the database and just use the php [in_array](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.in-array.php) command to see if they have chosen that activity.